# Do the symbols painted on the wall mean anything?

Tags: star-wars-jedi-survivor

Many areas of this game are blocked until you obtain some abilities, and I have often noticed that there are symbols painted on the wall nearby.

Here is an example, which seems to show three of these symbols. I have also seen one which looks like a J and backwards J, back to back.

[image: Swirl symbol, three lines symbol, crossed diamond symbol]

What do these symbols mean? If anything? Do they show what abilities you might need to clear this blockage?

They do not appear to be [Aurebesh](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Aurebesh)